# Compilation errors when I try to run ng serve

Tags: angular

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js 2011:15-24
"export 'ɵAPP_ROOT' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 2794:4-16
"export 'ɵLOCALE_DATA' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 2796:8-20
"export 'ɵLOCALE_DATA' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js 1876:23-38
"export 'ɵ_sanitizeStyle' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js 2010:28-43
"export 'ɵlooseIdentical' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js 1745:28-43
"export 'ɵlooseIdentical' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js 2352:12-27
"export 'ɵlooseIdentical' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 5393:12-27
"export 'ɵlooseIdentical' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 3293:8-23
"export 'ɵɵallocHostVars' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 4536:8-17
"export 'ɵɵstyling' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 3294:8-17
"export 'ɵɵstyling' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 4540:8-22
"export 'ɵɵstylingApply' was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js 3298:8-22
"export 'ɵɵstylingApply' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Comment: can an any one help me..

Comment: With this little information no one can help you. What Angular version are you using? What does your `package.json` and `angular.json` look like? Does the error happen only on your machine or does it not work in general? Does the error only happen when serving or also when building?

Comment: This is very little information to go on. Have you run npm install before you ng serve?